# Why is there a redirect from each page Vue?

Tags: vue.js, redirect

This code redirects all pages on my site.
How do I make only the page *`mysite.ru/404`* redirected to the page *`mysite.ru/404.php`*

**app.js**

```
import NotFound from './views/NotFound'

const router = new VueRouter({
  mode: 'history',
  routes: [
   { 
    path: '/404', 
    name: '404', 
    component: NotFound, 
   }, 
   { 
    path: '*', 
    redirect: '/404' 
   }
})
```

**NotFound.vue**

```
<template>
  <div id="404">Page Not Found</div>
</template>
<script>
    window.location.href = "/404.php"
</script>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to define all your routes as `path: '*'` will redirect all routes to not found if you have not defined them.

```
import NotFound from './views/NotFound'
import NewComponent from './views/NewComponent'

const router = new VueRouter({
  mode: 'history',
  routes: [
   {
    path: '/',
    component: NewComponent,
    children: [
      {
         path: '404',  // Changed
         name: '404', 
         component: NotFound
      }
    ]
   },
   { 
    path: '*', 
    redirect: '/404' 
   }
})
```

Now if you try `/` route it will redirect you to `NewComponent`
Its just an example. Hope it helps
And you should use `window.location.href = "/404.php"` inside created hook

```
<template>
  <div id="404">Page Not Found</div>
</template>
<script>
  export default {
     created () {
       window.location.href = "/404.php"
     }
  }
</script>
```

Comment: So it still redirect you to 404 page if you go to a route which exist ? As I can't see any route defined in your router

Comment: I have a lot of routes on the site, including the starting " / " but I didn't write about it here. And now all pages redirect to https://mysite/404.php

Comment: Are you using `/` in path of children if yes than just remove that like I did for `404` route in my answer.

Comment: `created()` throws an error when compiling: `Unexpected token, expected ";"`

Comment: Sorry, there was a missing export default, just added that

Comment: So sends to the page `mysite.ru/404` not `/404.php` and loads the site's start page

Comment: When a route don't exist it will redirect to /404 which will redirect to 404.php as we have set in created hook. It's just a simple change but it don't have anything to do with your problem. Have you check if your child routes path have `/` like `/404`